# Error: Cannot find module XXX (typescript aliases)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, babeljs, npx

It sounds like a common error. But in my case i can not find the reason. I am creating an NPM package as an backend-API for another project. I am using typescript and node.

I want to change my import statements from `import XX from "../../../XXX"` into `import XX from "@XX"`, am using PHP storm as code editor and it says that my code is good.

But when i run the script with npx `npx ts-node src/index` it will returns this:

```js
Error: Cannot find module '@authentication/SignUp'
Require stack:
- /Users/Youssef_1/Projects/driver-seat-amplify-api/src/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/Youssef_1/Projects/driver-seat-amplify-api/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Youssef_1/Projects/driver-seat-amplify-api/src/index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/Youssef_1/Projects/driver-seat-amplify-api/src/index.js' ]
}
```

My mapping:
[image]

index.ts:

```js
import {SignUp, ConfirmSignUp, ResendSignUp} from "@authentication/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./Authentication/SignIn";
import Validator from "./Services/Validator";
import {RegexPatterns, RegexTypes} from "./Enums/Regex";
import SignOut from "./Authentication/SignOut";
import DeleteAccount from "./Authentication/DeleteAccount";
import UserManagement from "./Authentication/UserManagement";
import "./app.config";

export default {
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
    SignOut,
    ConfirmSignUp,
    ResendSignUp,
    Validator,
    UserManagement,
    RegexPatterns,
    RegexTypes,
    DeleteUser: DeleteAccount,
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@authentication/*": ["Authentication/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-env",
        ["module-resolver", {
            "root": ["./src"],
            "alias": {
                "authentication": "./src/Authentication",
            }
        }]
    ],
    presets: [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This saved my day: [TS config path error. Error: Cannot find module '@/models/UserSchema'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70515063/) (accepted answer).

Installing ts-node fixed this issue for me.